# Filtering a relation in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, arel

I have this relation in my `Product` model:

```
has_many :features, :class_name => 'ProductFeature', :source => :product_feature, :include => :feature
```

So I can do `Product.features`

which works fine. But I want to be able to filter that by fields in the `feature` table, when and if necessary. For example in pseudo code:

```
find all product features where feature is comparable
```

`compare` is a bool field on the `feature`.

I have been trying for 2 hours solid and cannot figure it out (without writing a new query completely). I can't figure out how to access the `feature` table's fields from the `Product.features` relation, as it seems it can only filter on `product_features` fields.

This is what I have come up with so far:

```
def features_compare
  features.feature.where(:compare => true)
end
```

But it just says `feature` is not a valid method, which I understand.

## Edit

I have updated my model so the relationships are clearer:

product.rb:

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :company
  belongs_to :insurance_type

  has_many :product_features
  has_many :reviews

  attr_accessible :description, :name, :company
end
```

product_feature.rb:

```
class ProductFeature < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :feature

  delegate :name, :to => :feature

  attr_accessible :value
end
```

feature.rb

```
class Feature < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :compare
end
```

I want to be able to query the `product_features` that belong to a `product` and `feature` where `Feature.compare` is `true`. Something like this:

product.rb

```
def features_compare
  product_features.where(:compare => true)
end
```

This throws an error because `compare` in in the `Feature` model, not `ProductFeature`. I have tried the following in product_feature.rb:

```
delegate :compare, :to => :feature
```

but I didn't help.

I will adding a bounty to this in a few hours so please please help me!

Comment: I'm confused about the organization of the app. So you have a features table and a product_features table, and a Feature model and a ProductFeature model?

Comment: Also, you don't need the :source attribute since `has_many :features` isn't a `has_many :through` association.

Comment: And I'm starting to doubt that you need the `:include => :feature` part as well unless ProductFeature has a feature.

Comment: I can see how you would be! I have a Feature model which contains a set of features such as 'colour', 'size', 'shape' etc. Then a ProductFeature model which contains a link to the Product and Feature, and contains a 'value', such as 'black', 'medium', 'round' etc. I have renamed the relation to 'features' rather than 'product_features' on the Product model for better readability (or so I hoped lol)

Comment: I need the include so I can access the feature name through the relation

Comment: Oh, I see. I think I have your answer. I'll revise mine below.

Comment: Great thank you. Incidentally, just revisited and you're right I didn't need include. FYI, I am very new to Rails ;)

Comment: @JoshuaRieken I have updated my question, see if it makes any more sense to you...

Comment: @JoshuaRieken This new Railscast explains my situation perfectly! http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find all product features where feature is comparable` is just

```
ProductFeature.joins(:feature).where(:feature => {:compare => true})
```

You can make that a bit more reusable by introducing a scope:

```
#in product_feature.rb
scope :with_feature_like, lambda do |filter|
   joins(:feature).where(:feature => filter)
end

#elsewhere
ProductFeature.with_feature_like(:compare => true)

#all the product features of a certain product with at comparable features
some_product.product_features.with_feature_like(:compare => true)
```

Finally, if you want all products with product features with comparable features, you want something like:

```
Product.joins(:product_features => :feature).where(:feature => {:compare => true})
```

which of course you can also turn into a scope on `Product`.

Comment: Is there no way to do the filter directly on the product_features relation of Product then? IE product_features.where(:features => {:compare => true}) ?

Comment: Sure you can, but you need to join first. So `some_product.product_features.joins(:features).where(:features => {:compare => true})`. That's all my `some_product` example in the answer is doing, except it hid the details in the scope.

Comment: Ok, would I still need to join if I've set ProductFeature to includes :feature ?

Comment: (BTW, I just edited my answer to use `:feature` instead of `:features`. I'd forgotten there's only one feature per product feature.)

When you say "includes", do you mean with delegate? Yeah, all delegate does is turn calls to `product_feature.compare` into `product_feature.feature.compare`. It doesn't affect querying at all.

Comment: Oh ok cool. I shall use this post to guide me in a bit and will report how I get on! Thanks!

Comment: One way to think about all that is to notice that if `delegate` *did* affect querying, it would have to do so by writing a join on the sly, since the relevant data lives on a different table. Another thing it could do but doesn't is copy/update the field to an extra column in the `product_features` table. You can actually achieve that kind of denormalization on your own with a bit of work (or a gem), and there are situations that call for that. But unless you've got a a pressing reason to do that, I'd just stick with doing your own joins. It's certainly the simplest solution.

Comment: Yeh that worked great, except I put it in a class method rather than scope! Thanks man

Answer (score 1):

This seems like a has_many :through relationship. Try changing this:

```
has_many :features, :class_name => 'ProductFeature', :source => :product_feature, :include => :feature
```

to this:

```
has_many :product_features
has_many :features, :through => :product_features
```

As long as your ProductFeature model has this:

```
belongs_to :product
belongs_to :feature
```

And you have the appropriate columns on product_features (product_id, feature_id), then you should be able to access that product's features and all the attributes on both Product and ProductFeature.

See here:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has_many-through-association

EDIT: Here's how to filter by feature fields.

```
Product.joins(:features).where(:features => {:name => "Size"})
```

Comment: Hmmm. But that will just say: Unknown column 'product_features.compare'

Comment: Did you try, @MattHumphrey, or are you just speculating?

Comment: It shouldn't say that if you've written the migration for product_features that adds the compare field and run it.

Comment: No I did try, and I know why. The relation, features, is actually a product_feature relation.

Comment: I have updated the question with the model context @JoshuaRieken

Comment: Revised answer based on new design info.

Comment: But now I cannot access the value attribute of ProductFeature.. This is how I originally had it set up.

Comment: How are you trying to access it?

Comment: Product.first.features[0].value

Comment: Product.first.product_features.first.value is what you're looking for.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/23067/discussion-between-matt-humphrey-and-joshua-rieken)

Answer (score 0):

`@product.each |p| { p.features.where(:comparable => true) }` is probably your best bet here, but I'm open to being enlightened.